# Lets turn the blinking off ... on .. off.. on ... PERMANTENTLY OFF

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

The [blinking tag](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/blinking) is used in 18 questions.   Mostly about blinking LEDs, cursors and monitors which turn on and off.

I suggest we permanently blink it out of existence.

Comment: For any British readers, can you clarify which blinking tag you're referring to?  :-)

Comment: durr, it's next to the flipping switches. under the blooming flowers.

Comment: 10 upvotes is consensus enough.